# Can CSS class change based on whether specific child is or is not present?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with class "thumbnail". It will always have a child div of class "image1" but may or may not have a child div of class "text".

Is there any way for the parent class to change based on whether there is no div.text or if it only has div.image1? In my case I would like to make the div.thumbnail have a black background (see div.thumbnail:doesNotHave(div.text) in CSS below). Ultimately, I want to do more complex things here but simplified here for this question.

I know that I can make a div.thumbnail.single as with the example but was looking to see if there is a way for this to be detected in CSS without the subclass.

```css
div.thumbnail
{
    background-color: green;
    padding : 1em;
}

div.thumbnail.single
{
    background-color: blue;
}

/* ??? something that does this */
div.thumbnail:doesNotHave(div.text)
{
    background-color: black;
}

div.thumbnail div.image1
{
    background-color : cyan;
}

div.thumbnail div.text
{
    background-color : orange;
}

div.thumbnail div.text span.title
{
    background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image and Text</h2>

<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="image1">
        image 1
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        text
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Image Only (Single)</h2>

<div class="thumbnail single">
    <div class="image1">
        image 1
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Image Only</h2>

<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="image1">
        image 1
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I think what you mean to ask is if there is a css selector that can react based on children of the element rather than asking if the class can change.

Comment: Yes, I want to know if there is a css select that can react based on children of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found the only way now is to use a subclass. So div.thumbnail.single is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

There is `:has` pseudo class. However, [it is not supported by any browser](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

Answer (score 1):

A generic answer is no but for your particular case you can do the background part like below:

```css
div.thumbnail {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;
  position:relative; /* relative here */
  z-index:0;
}

div.thumbnail.single {
  background-color: blue;
}
/* a pseudo element applied to text that will play the role of your background layer */
div.thumbnail div.text::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: black;
}
/**/

div.thumbnail div.image1 {
  background-color: cyan;
}

div.thumbnail div.text {
  background-color: orange;
}

div.thumbnail div.text span.title {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image and Text</h2>

<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image1">
    image 1
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    text
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Image Only (Single)</h2>

<div class="thumbnail single">
  <div class="image1">
    image 1
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Image Only</h2>

<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="image1">
    image 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

[`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) is coming someday, maybe. In the meantime not really, though in certain use cases you might be be able to make something work with [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) or [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)